# How to associate an event to Html.ActionLink in MVC3

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I have made an Ajax function but i am getting a big prolem in that.
I was displaying the contents on click of the link..
The links are fetched from the database and also the url of the links are fetched from the datbase.
I have wriiten ajax to call the contents dynamically on click of the link

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var filename = $(this).text();
   var Hobbyurl = '@Url.Action("FetchUrlByHobbyName")';
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: Hobbyurl,
            data: { data: filename },
            success: function (returndata) {
            $('iframe').attr('src', returndata);
            }
                    });
                });
            });
  </script>
```

Now FetchUrlByHobbyName is the function called from the Controller thart returns the url

```
 //Ajax routine to fetch the hobbyinfo by hobbyname
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FetchUrlByHobbyName(string data)
    {
        HobbyMasters hobbymaster = new HobbyHomeService().FetchHobbyMasterByHobbyName(data);
        string url = hobbymaster.InformationUrl;
        if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return Json(url);
        return View();
    }
```

And in my View i have written the link like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <li >@Html.ActionLink(item.HobbyName, "Hobbies")
   </li>
}
```

i tried this :

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.HobbyName, "Hobbies", null, new { id = "alink" })
```

and then calling Ajax on click of 'alink' but with this my ajax function doesnot get called.
**Now the problem is the ajax function is getting called on click of every link on the page**..
I want to assign a unique Id to it but i am not understanding how to do that
please Help me...

Answer (score 2):

For that specific link, assign an id. E.g

```
<a id="someID" href="url">Link</a>
```

and than bind the click only with that link.

```
$('#someID').click(function (e)) ....
```

Comment: hey thanx for the reply.i have updated my question can u please see and tell me how should i put the id to Html.ActionLink.

Comment: You are assigning same id in `foreach` loop to links. Either assign a unique id to links and than bind or an easy solution is instead use a class, e.g.  `new {class="hobbieClass"}` and than bind `$('.hobbieClass')`

Comment: hey this also does not work my ajax function doesnt get calle thru this

Comment: You will probably need to precede the keyword class with an '@' symbol as it's a reserved word in C#.  `new { @class = "hobbieClass" }`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly this helps you

```
<a href="/somepath" id="mySuperLink" onclick="myAjaxFunction()">The text of the link</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myAjaxFunction(){
       e.preventDefault();
       var filename = $(this).text();
       var Hobbyurl = '@Url.Action("FetchUrlByHobbyName")';
       $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: Hobbyurl,
                data: { data: filename },
                success: function (returndata) {
                $('iframe').attr('src', returndata);
                }
      });


  </script>
```

Comment: Hey thanx for the reply  i have updated my question please see and tell me how can i call my ajaxfunction in HTML.ActionLink.

Comment: Hi i wrote this and tried to call this method like this:
@Html.ActionLink(item.HobbyName, "Hobbies", null, new {onclick = "myAjaxFunction()" }) But i am getting an error saying Object Required am i missing something???

Answer (score 0):

Try to give a css class selector to you action link like this...

```
@Html.ActionLink("some link", "Create", "Some_Controller", new { }, new { @class = "test" })
```

then User jquery for it..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.test').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var filename = $(this).text();
   var Hobbyurl = '@Url.Action("FetchUrlByHobbyName")';
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: Hobbyurl,
            data: { data: filename },
            success: function (returndata) {
            $('iframe').attr('src', returndata);
            }
                    });
                });
            });
  </script>
```

Comment: Hi i tried ur method but this is strange my ajax is not getting called through that...and evn i trid this:
@Html.ActionLink(item.HobbyName, "Hobbies", null, new {onclick = "myAjaxFunction()" }) and renamed the function as myAjaxfunction() removing first two lines.But i get an error saying object required.Can u tell me why is that coming.with this the ajax function is getting called

Comment: new {@onclick = "myAjaxFunction()" } add @ before onclick